# centrally align icons in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout

I want the icons to be centrally placed on the screen with proper alignment. What are the parameters I need to set?
I have tried android:gravity and android:layout_gravity but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

set the image `scaleType` to `centerInside`

Comment: did you set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent`, and if your api level is 11 set it to `match_parent`